# generate all set/get for an object

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have an object that  it contains multiple set and get. Example:

```
MettreAJourPersonne entree = new MettreAJourPersonne();
        entree.setLnPEO("CHANTRAIT");
        entree.setLpPEO("THERESE");
        entree.setLnPEOPNY("");
        entree.setCdPEOSEX("F");
        entree.setCdPEOSMT("C");
        entree.set .........
```

How to generate all the get/set automatically of the object entree?

thx

EDIT:

My object MettreAJourPersonne:

```
public class MettreAJourPersonne {

private String lnPEO;
private String lpPEO;
private String lnPEOPNY;
private String cdPEOSEX;
private String cdPEOSMT;
private String ayPEOFIS;
private String alPEOCOUCMP;
private String alPEOCOUBAT;
private String alPEOCOURUE;
private String alPEOCARCMP;
private String acPEOCOU;
private String alPEOCOUCMN;
private String ayPEOCOU;
.........(more elements).....



/**
 * @return the lnPEO
 */
public String getLnPEO() {
    return lnPEO;
}

/**
 * @param lnPEO
 *            the lnPEO to set
 */
public void setLnPEO(String lnPEO) {
    this.lnPEO = lnPEO;
}

/**
 * @return the lpPEO
 */
public String getLpPEO() {
    return lpPEO;
}

/**
 * @param lpPEO
 *            the lpPEO to set
 */
public void setLpPEO(String lpPEO) {
    this.lpPEO = lpPEO;
}

/**
 * @return the lnPEOPNY
 */
public String getLnPEOPNY() {
    return lnPEOPNY;
}

/**
 * @param lnPEOPNY
 *            the lnPEOPNY to set
 */
public void setLnPEOPNY(String lnPEOPNY) {
    this.lnPEOPNY = lnPEOPNY;
}

/**
 * @return the cdPEOSEX
 */
public String getCdPEOSEX() {
    return cdPEOSEX;
}

/**
 * @param cdPEOSEX
 *            the cdPEOSEX to set
 */
public void setCdPEOSEX(String cdPEOSEX) {
    this.cdPEOSEX = cdPEOSEX;
}

/**
 * @return the cdPEOSMT
 */
public String getCdPEOSMT() {
    return cdPEOSMT;
}

/**
 * @param cdPEOSMT
 *            the cdPEOSMT to set
 */
public void setCdPEOSMT(String cdPEOSMT) {
    this.cdPEOSMT = cdPEOSMT;
}

/**
 * @return the ayPEOFIS
 */
public String getAyPEOFIS() {
    return ayPEOFIS;
}

/**
 * @param ayPEOFIS
 *            the ayPEOFIS to set
 */
public void setAyPEOFIS(String ayPEOFIS) {
    this.ayPEOFIS = ayPEOFIS;
}

/**
 * @return the alPEOCOUCMP
 */
public String getAlPEOCOUCMP() {
    return alPEOCOUCMP;
}

/**
 * @param alPEOCOUCMP
 *            the alPEOCOUCMP to set
 */
public void setAlPEOCOUCMP(String alPEOCOUCMP) {
    this.alPEOCOUCMP = alPEOCOUCMP;
}

/**
 * @return the alPEOCOUBAT
 */
public String getAlPEOCOUBAT() {
    return alPEOCOUBAT;
}

/**
 * @param alPEOCOUBAT
 *            the alPEOCOUBAT to set
 */
public void setAlPEOCOUBAT(String alPEOCOUBAT) {
    this.alPEOCOUBAT = alPEOCOUBAT;
}

/**
 * @return the alPEOCOURUE
 */
public String getAlPEOCOURUE() {
    return alPEOCOURUE;
}

/**
 * @param alPEOCOURUE
 *            the alPEOCOURUE to set
 */
public void setAlPEOCOURUE(String alPEOCOURUE) {
    this.alPEOCOURUE = alPEOCOURUE;
}

/**
 * @return the alPEOCARCMP
 */
public String getAlPEOCARCMP() {
    return alPEOCARCMP;
}

/**
 * @param alPEOCARCMP
 *            the alPEOCARCMP to set
 */
public void setAlPEOCARCMP(String alPEOCARCMP) {
    this.alPEOCARCMP = alPEOCARCMP;
}

/**
 * @return the acPEOCOU
 */
public String getAcPEOCOU() {
    return acPEOCOU;
}

/**
 * @param acPEOCOU
 *            the acPEOCOU to set
 */
public void setAcPEOCOU(String acPEOCOU) {
    this.acPEOCOU = acPEOCOU;
}

/**
 * @return the alPEOCOUCMN
 */
public String getAlPEOCOUCMN() {
    return alPEOCOUCMN;
}

/**
 * @param alPEOCOUCMN
 *            the alPEOCOUCMN to set
 */
public void setAlPEOCOUCMN(String alPEOCOUCMN) {
    this.alPEOCOUCMN = alPEOCOUCMN;
}

/**
 * @return the ayPEOCOU
 */
public String getAyPEOCOU() {
    return ayPEOCOU;
}

/**
 * @param ayPEOCOU
 *            the ayPEOCOU to set
 */
public void setAyPEOCOU(String ayPEOCOU) {
    this.ayPEOCOU = ayPEOCOU;
}
............(more get and set)
```

Now, i want to use the object MettreAJourPersonne() in other class, and automatically generate all the set in the other class

```
MettreAJourPersonne entree = new MettreAJourPersonne();
            entree.setLnPEO("CHANTRAIT");
            entree.setLpPEO("THERESE");
            entree.setLnPEOPNY("");
            entree.setCdPEOSEX("F");
            entree.setCdPEOSMT("C");
            entree.set .........
```

Now, I must write (by hand) every call to the method set: example

```
entree.setLnPeo("A")
entree.setLpPeo("B")
```

..

Comment: Have a look at project Lombok. It will generate your setter and getters automatically at compile.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `MettreAJourPersonne`-Source in eclipse and press ALT-SHIFT-S then on Generate Getter/Setter and configure your wishes.

Comment: Ithas all the get of the classe  MettreAJourPersonnethey  been already declared. But now I want to use them without  generating one for one with CTRL+Espace

Comment: i dont understand your problem sorry. Can you specify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

press `ALT+SHIFT+s` then `press r` , 
select variable  which u want to create setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on eclipse coding window ->select "source" option -> click on Generate setter and getter option. you can generate easily all properties setter getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin **lombok** no need to write set/get method. Annotation works every thing. Just add following dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Use like below:
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

```
/**
 *
 * @author devb
 */
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {

    private String name;
}
```

For Testing another class is:

```
/**
 *
 * @author devb
 */
public class AnnotationSetGetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Bhuwan");
        System.out.println(person.getName());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bhuwan
```

See More On : [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html)